# Error Plotting Local Fisher Discriminant Analysis {lfda} package

Tags: r, plot

I am running Plotting Local Fisher Discriminant Analysis ldfa {lfda} package, I use a data frame as showed below:

```
> dim (df)
[1]  35 415

 model <- lfda(df[, 2:ncol(df)], df[, 1], r = 3, metric="plain")
```

I get this error:

```
Error in getAffinityMatrix(distance2, knn, nc) : 
  knn is too large, please try to reduce it.
```

knn is a parameter used in local scaling method (default: 5)
I have tested lower values than 5 (4,3,2,1) but still I get another error:

```
Error in solve.default(tSw) : 
system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.90897e-24
```

I am not sure what is the problem and what I should do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `lfda` yields the `system is computationally singular` error message when one of the explanatory variables is perfectly associated to the response variable.
 In the example that follows I consider the `iris` dataset:

```
X <- iris[,-5]
y <- iris[,5]
```

I generate an X variable perfectly associated to `y`:

```
X$xnew <- (iris[,5]=="virginica")
```

and `lfda` generates the error message:

```
result <- lfda(X, y, r=3, metric="plain")
```

> Error in solve.default(tSw) :  system is computationally singular:
>   reciprocal condition number = 6.85339e-28

Hope this can help you to find the solution for your problem.

Comment: Not clear where you store `xnew` and when do you it? Also where is `k` in the last line?

Comment: I assume `k` is in reality `X`